# Are these real Lego figures?

Tags: minifigure-identification

Are these real LEGO figures or custom non-LEGO designs?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes they are. The top figure is made out of these parts:

- Head: [Item 3626bpb0220](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=3626bpb0220#T=S&C=3&O=%7B%22color%22:3,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D)

  [image]
- Hair: [Item 3901](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=3901#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D)

[image]

- Torso: [Item 973c19 but with yellow hands](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=973c19#T=S&C=3&O=%7B%22color%22:3,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D)

[image]

- Legs: [Item 970c00](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=970c00&idColor=63#T=S&C=3&O=%7B%22color%22:%223%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D)

[image]

The bottom figure has the same torso as the top figure, and these parts:

- Head: I cannot find this as a LEGO provided minifig head print, but there are several ways to customize LEGO heads, like through [minifigs.me](http://minifigs.me) so this could be a custom head not produced by LEGO.
- Hair: [Item 4530 in Tan](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=4530#T=S&C=2&O=%7B%22color%22:%222%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D)

[image]

- The lower body is made out of the following Yellow bricks:

  - A [3023 Plate 1x2](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=3023#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) for the hips
  - Two [3062b Brick, Round 1x1 Open Stud](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=3062b#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) for the legs

Comment: The head reminds me of the freckled boy face from a few years ago. Also it's worth pointing out that while these are official Lego pieces, this particular arrangement is strictly unofficial.

Comment: Freckled boy face probably refers to this face: [http://img.bricklink.com/P/3/3626bpx19.gif](http://img.bricklink.com/P/3/3626bpx19.gif) / [Bricklink page](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=3626bpx19&idColor=3#T=C&C=3)